# Cannot enter something in Database MYSQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to put some information automatically in my database but it only works the first time. If I reload the page it doesn't put it in again.

This is my code:

```
<?php
require '../overig/connect.php';
require '../overig/secure.php'; 
$userr = $_SESSION['email'];
$user = md5($userr); 
$friend2 = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$friend = substr($friend2, 6, 25);
$Q = 1;
$A = 0;
if((isset($user)) || isset($friend)) {
    $add = "INSERT INTO `friends` (p1,p2,Q,A) VALUES ('$user','$friend','$Q','$A')";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $add);
} else {
  echo 'hello';
}
?>
```

I hope you can help me :)

Comment: your database may be set up to not allow duplicate entries of the same data

Comment: Yes, it can do that. I tried that already.

Comment: What do your web server's error logs say?

Comment: I got no web server error log.

Comment: `if (!mysqli_query($con, $add)) {
    printf("Errormessage: %s\n", mysqli_error($con));
}` to see db error. Also does echo 'hello' run?

Comment: You check if the variables you explicitly set, are set - and they always will be when you do that. You perhaps want `!empty()`, and to use `&&` (AND) instead of `||` (OR). Enable error-reporting and check your logs, by adding `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the top of your code

Comment: I got this "Errormessage: Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'" And I understand why. Thank you for helping me!!

Comment: You got no error log?

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you convert this:

> "INSERT INTO `friends` (p1,p2,Q,A) VALUES
>   ('$user','$friend','$Q','$A')";"

into the generated sql and get something like this:

```
INSERT INTO friends (p1,p2,Q,A) VALUES ('John','Jim','This','That');
```

What would happen if you tried to run that twice?
I suspect you would only see one row like this:

```
|John|Jim |This|That|
```

But really you are expecting:

```
|John|Jim |This|That|    
|John|Jim |This|That|
```

To achieve this consider changing your database and scripts so you get a result more like this:

```
|1   |John|Jim |This|That|    
|2   |John|Jim |This|That|
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this:

```
echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($con));
```

below this row:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, $add);
```

and you should what the problem is.